# Hide basic authentication popup with jquery in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I use this code for a basic anthentification of REST API. Unfortunately, when the user/pass is wrong Google Chrome displays a popup. Firefox does not do that.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ad",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    success: function (){
        alert('success');
        return false;
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Edit 1 :**

I use Laravel Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have server control, there is no (at least not known to me) way to prevent that. If you DO have server control you can do two things:

1. Change the response status code from standard 401 to something else. However, this is commonly not known as best practice since the status code does then not state the actual issue (authentication error).
2. Change the response header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="your_realm"` to a custom value like `WWW-Authenticate: x-Basic realm="your_realm"` (Note the `x-`there!).

That should prevent any default login handling.

**Update 1**

As for using Laravel [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415369/fully-disable-cookies-in-laravel-4-api%20here) would be an example of setting the correct response header `WWW-Authenticate` (changed `Basic` to `x-Basic`):

```php
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    $credentials = ['email' => Request::getUser(), 'password' => Request::getPassword()];

    if (!Auth::once($credentials)) {
        $response   = ['error' => true, 'message' => 'Unauthorized request'];
        $code       = 401;
        $headers    = ['WWW-Authenticate' => 'x-Basic'];

        return Response::json($response, $code, $headers);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in symfony?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the username and password in the URL instead for HTTP authentication.
Give this a shot:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://username:password@whatever.com/ad",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (){
        alert('success');
        return false;
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it does not change anything for me