# how to make stateless web app with laravel

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4, session-cookies, session-state

I will be using stateless web app architecture. For authentication I will be encrypting the authenticationid and putting it in client cookie and sending it to client as described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49145/avoid-hitting-db-to-authenticate-a-user-on-every-request-in-stateless-web-app-ar).

But I see that when a get request is send to the server, the response contains a cookie named `laravel_session`. I've read that for a stateless architecture, there should be no session as otherwise it would mean that session state is stored at server.

**How to remove any kind of session  from laravel to make my app stateless?**

Comment: My bad, there's a related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415369/fully-disable-cookies-in-laravel-4-api/21717582#21717582.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set session driver:

- Laravel v5.7.0: [config/session.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.7.0/config/session.php)
- Laravel v4.2.0: [app/config/session.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v4.2.0/app/config/session.php)

**cookie** - a cookie-based session driver where session data is encrypted in the user's cookies.

**array** - session data is saved in a PHP array. Take note that the array session driver does not support persistence and is usually only used in console commands and tests.